# Как из массива занести данные в БД?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [55] => Ягафарова
    [58] => Азарова
    [97] => Квятковская
    [101] => Лештаев
)
```

Это всё, мне нужно занести в БД, в столбик testes начиная с первого id.
Как это сделать?

Comment: А что именно вам надо занести в БД, ключ массива куда нибудь заносится ? Какова структура таблицы в которую сохраняются записи

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// создаём подключение
$conn = newmysqli($servername,            $username,     $password, $dbname);
// проверяем установлено ли соединение
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
foreach(tvoi_array as $value ){
$sql = "INSERT INTO  testers_tbl     (testers)
VALUES (". $value.")";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: _Никогда_ не используйте и тем более не рекомендуйте использовать подстановку значений переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. Это потенциально ведет к sql-инъекциям, неожиданным сбоям и замедляет работу. _Всегда_ используйте подготовленные выражения и привязку значений http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  По хорошему, запрос insert должен быть подготовлен перед началом цикла, а в цикле только execute запроса с привязкой очередного значения